# Compatibility of source code between windows IDE and gcc?

Tags: c, windows, gcc

I'm grappling with some homework which was requested as linux gcc compatible (and limited to the libraries stdio, stdlib and string). However, being unfamiliar with Linux and having to code without an IDE makes this not a pleasant experience.

Is there any reason why, sticking to the above libraries, I could make code that doesn't run the same in a windows IDE and linux' gcc? If so, is there specific factors I could avoid to keep the source code compatible between the two?

Comment: Use gcc in the windows IDE and avoid making any windows-specific system calls

Comment: The assignment involves creation and management of files, will that make it incompatible with Windows?

Comment: You can use the Standard C file management